# How to use return in a java function

Tags: java

My function is to make the code below print out 'Math' at an even number and 'English' at an odd number and repeat the process five times.

```
public static String[] subject() {  
    String[] subjects = { 'Math', 'English' };
    int i=0;
    while (i<5) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            System.out.println(subjects[0]);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(subjects[1]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return subjects;
} 

public static void main(String[]args) {
    for(int n=0; n<5; n++) {
        subject();
    }
```

Originally it's double quotes, but I don't know how to do it, so I put single quotes.
It works, but I don't know how to use the return exactly.
I understand placing variable after return makes it the same type, ends the method and calls the result.
so why should I write a variable name, instead of writing the name of the function.

sorry im not good at English so had to refer to a translator to help

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: If all you want to do is print those values you don't need to return anything. I don't see any reason why that method couldn't be `public static void` instead.

Comment: You don't know how to put int double-quotes? This should just be a key on your keyboard. Single quoted used like that should cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For this requirement, you should declare the return type as `void` as you just want to print the elements from the array and you are not using the returned array.
2. You need to remove the loop from inside `main` because it's already there in your method, `subject`.
3. `0` is neither an odd number nor an even number. So, you should start with `i = 1` and the terminating condition of the loop should be `i <= 5`.
4. In Java, single quotes are used to enclose `char` literals. To enclose `String` literals, you need to use double-quotes. Note that many languages, especially scripting languages and SQL, support enclosing `String` literals using single quotes.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void subject() {
        String[] subjects = { "Math", "English" };
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 5) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(subjects[0]);
            } else {
                System.out.println(subjects[1]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subject();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
English
Math
English
Math
English
```

Comment: Regarding item (3) and the point that _"0 is neither an odd number nor an even number"_, what happens if you change `int i = 1;` to `int i = 0`? Zero is an even number in Java (and in mathematics, generally). Let me know if I missed the point.

Comment: @andrewjames -  It has been always a point of debate even though it has been accepted as an even number in Mathematics. There is an interesting article [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-20559052). When it comes to Java, it has been used in both ways e.g. the first element in an array or a string has the index, `0`; the first month in the `java.util` date API is `0`. On the other hand, the first month in the modern `java.time` API is `1`; the first param in `PreparedStatement` and the first field in a `ResultSet` have the index, `1`.

Comment: _"it has been used in both ways"_ In which of the above cases you mention is `0` an even number, and in which cases is it an odd number?  I think I am still missing something fundamental, here.

Comment: @andrewjames - My aim was to help the OP to get past the problem he faced and the solution was able to meet the objective. Whether `0` is an odd or even in Java can be a separate discussion.

Comment: OK - understood. It is an interesting area. I think Java - the core language & spec - does not have anything to say about which numbers are even and which are odd (maybe I am wrong about that). If we choose to use a definition, such as "i is an even integer if `i % 2 == 0`" - then that is just one possible choice we can make. I suppose there could be other definitions, also.